# basic getter method with PHP

Tags: php, html, getter-setter

I am trying to write a basic getter method however I cannot seem to get it to work. I have a good background in java but I am new to php. I just need to be able to have access to the area data for my isosceles triangle object. Ive written a hole bunch of code so I tried to make a small example.

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>

<?php 

class Isosceles  {
private $height;
private $base;
private $area;
private $perm;

function __construct($base, $height) {
    $this->base = $base;
    $this->height = $height;
    $this->area = (($base * $height) / 2);
    $this->perm = sqrt((pow($base, 2) + pow($height, 2))) + $base + $height;
}

function __getBase(){
    return $this->base;
}

function __getHeight(){
    return $this->height;
}

function __getArea(){
    return $this->area;
}

function __getPerm(){
    return $this->perm;
}

function __toString() {
    return  "base: " . $this->base . "<br> height: " .  $this->height . "<br> Area: " . $this->area . "<br> perimeter: " . $this->perm;
}
}

$isocelesObject = new Isosceles(5,3);
echo $isocelesObject;
echo $isocelesObject->getArea();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

what I get for the output is:

```
 base: 5
 height: 3
 Area: 7.5
 perimeter: 13.830951894845
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method Isosceles::getArea() in isosceles.php on line 45
```

so the toString method is actually working but the getter isnt. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think your $isocelesObject->getArea() must be changed into $isocelesObject->_getArea() if you want to use setter and getter you can refer to this https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Comment: Thank you very much you just saved me big time. Cant believe it was a syntax error.